# Tkinter OOP updating widget in instance method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

My system prints a GUI of an queue of customer orders. When an order is complete, the worker presses complete, and all items should shift across the GUI, removing the popped item.

The formatting came out incorrectly but indentation is correct in my idle. I have received this error upon pressing the <kbd>Comlete</kbd> button and do not know how to fix it. I have minimal experience with tkinter and OOP

```
File "C:\Users\stecd\Desktop\NEA - Copy\Order Queue.py", line 68, in orderFulfilled
    self.button = Label(master,text=item,width=30,height=5,bg="red")
NameError: name 'master' is not defined
```

Code:

```
class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.completedButton = Button(master,text="Complete",width=30,height=5,bg="green")
        self.completedButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.completedButton.bind('<Button-1>', self.orderFulfilled)

        for item in customerQueue.queue:
            self.button = Label(master,text=item,width=30,height=5,bg="red")
            self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

    def orderFulfilled(self, event):
        customerQueue.dequeue()
        self.button.pack_forget()

        for item in customerQueue.queue:
            self.button = Label(master,text=item,width=30,height=5,bg="red")
            self.button.pack(side=LEFT)


root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should be using `self.master`.

Answer (score -1):

[quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58665335/python-tkinter-oop-updating-widget-in-instance-method/58665438#comment103633894_58665335) that

> You should be using `self.master`.

This answered my question.

Comment: This post is not an answer but rather more of a comment.